# How can I produce model_sum <- models %>% glimpse(mod) in txhousing dataset. The original uses 'glance" but it no longer exists

Tags: r, broom

In the book by Wickham he works with the txhousing data set and produces the data frame in question by using the glance function from the broom package. That function has been removed and now in the tidyverse glimpse exists. However, you cannot simple replace glance with glimpse. I have been searching diligently but cannot seem to find an answer.

```
glimpse(models)

model_sum <- models %>% (mod)

model_sum
```

The following error occurs:

```
Error in models %>% (mod) : attempt to apply non-function
```

Comment: Your error suggests that `glimpse(models)` works fine and the problem is the following line, `models %>% (mod)`, which is equivalent to `mod(models)`. I'm unfamiliar with the `mod()` function so I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: When was `glance` removed from `broom`? I don't think that's correct. https://broom.tidymodels.org/reference/glance.lm.html

Comment: `glimpse` is a function of `dplyr` for examining data frames, while `glance` from `broom` is for looking at model objects.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking at the 2016 edition of "ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis." http://www.ievbras.ru/ecostat/Kiril/R/Biblio_N/R_Eng/Wickham2016.pdf

The [current version](https://ggplot2-book.org/) of the ggplot2 book doesn't go into modeling and leaves that for another Wickham book, the [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/model-intro.html) book that focuses more on dplyr and tidyr.

In the time since 2016, the tidyverse team has updated some of the approaches and syntax used there, so it doesn't look like that code will run verbatim any more.

In the 2016 ggplot2 book, there is code that defines

```
models <- txhousing %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  do(mod = lm(log2(sales) ~ factor(month), data = ., na.action = na.exclude))
```

so that `models` has a `mod` column. Older versions of broom could run

```
model_sum <- models %>%
  broom::glance(mod) # I'm using v1.0.1
```

but now doing so gives you an error that could understandably make one think that `glance` was replaced by `glimpse`:

```
Error: There is no glance method for tibbles. Did you mean `tibble::glimpse()`?
```

The problem is that [`broom 0.5.0` in 2018 included breaking changes](https://broom.tidymodels.org/news/index.html#breaking-changes-0-5-0) that made it more selective about how it could work; it could no longer run on a list column directly, but rather was expected to be in a `mutate` - `map` syntax.

If you want to practice modeling with the tidyverse as it exists in 2023, I'd focus on the updated approaches in the R4DS link above. It would suggest something like:

```
models2 <- txhousing %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(mod =    map(data, 
                      ~lm(log2(sales) ~ factor(month),
                      data = ., 
                      na.action = na.exclude)),
         glance = map(mod,
                      broom::glance))
```

You might also look at this useful vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html